# Swagger ReaderListener Not Invoked

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to invoke the afterScan(...) method from the ReaderListener interface but it is not being called.  Here's my code:

```
@SwaggerDefinition( info = @Info(
    description = "My API",
    version = "V1.2.3",
    title = "The only API you'll ever need",
    termsOfService = "share and care",
    contact = @Contact(name = "Test-Bob", email = "test-bob@tester.io", url = "http://swagger.io"),
    license = @License(name = "Apache 2.0", url = "http://www.apache.org")))
    @Api(tags = {"something", "else"})
    @Path("/myUrl/swagger/{type:json|yaml}")
    public class MyApiListingResource extends BaseApiListingResource implements ReaderListener {

      private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApiListingResource.class); 

      @Context ServletContext context;

      @GET
      @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/yaml"})
      @ApiOperation(value = "The swagger definition in either JSON or YAML", 
        hidden = true)
      public Response getListing(@Context Application app, @Context ServletConfig servletConfig, @Context HttpHeaders headers,
                @Context UriInfo uriInfo, @PathParam("type") String type) throws JsonProcessingException {

            if (isNotBlank(type) && type.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yaml")) {

                return getListingYamlResponse(app, context, servletConfig, headers, uriInfo);

            } else {

                System.out.println("I found json!");
                logger.debug("I'm also before!!!");

                return getListingJsonResponse(app, context, servletConfig, headers, uriInfo);
            }
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {

      System.out.println("I'm before!!!");
      logger.debug("I'm also before!!!");

      } 

      @Override
      public void afterScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {

      System.out.println("I'm after!!!");
      logger.debug("I'm also after!!!");     

      }

    }
```

Now when I call the following service:

```
http://localhost:9081/myApp/myUrl/swagger/json
```

I do receive the "I found json!" in my console and log...but none of the "before" or "after" comments are printed in the console or log.

I'm using Swagger 1.5.10 and Java 7.  I'll provide any other details that are needed.

Any ideas are welcome!  Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**:  I tried adding the @SwaggerDefinition annotation to this class as shown above, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the issue here.  Apparently the problem with the original design was that I was extending `BaseApiListingResource` on the same class where I was trying to implement ReaderListener.  For whatever reason (feel free to comment if you know why) the `ReaderListener` wasn't working whenever I extend `BaseApiListingResource`.  If I implement `ReaderListener` on a class that doesn't extend `BaseApiListingResource` then *`beforeScan`* and *`afterScan`* work just fine.

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

We are in 2023 and things moved ahead.
Here is what I did to make it functional. I use vanilla jaxrs jars.

- Create Class implementing `ReaderListener` (io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.ReaderListener)
- Annotate it `@OpenAPIDefinition` (io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition)
- Register `JaxrsAnnotationScanner` as a scannerClass via `SwaggerConfiguration` instance
- if your implementation of `ReaderListener` is in the different package than other resources, register it as resource class via `SwaggerConfiguration` instance as well

Keep in mind, scanner works **lazily**. To see something in your logs, you must **invoke url** to generate openapi definition.